# FaceDetector module not found. Make sure expo-face-detector is installed and linked correctly

Tags: react-native, expo

I have expo-sdk 49 installed and I get this error

[image]

as of now i have the latest `expo-face-detector` installed

```
"dependencies": {
    "expo": "^49.0.0",
    "expo-camera": "~13.4.2",
    "expo-face-detector": "~12.2.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.3",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.6"
  },
```

I deleted `package.lock.json` and node_modules reinstalled everything but still having the same error

Comment: Any solution, I am in this situation now

Comment: Expo Face Detector has been removed from Expo Go. Read more about the reasoning behind this change and how to work around it [here](https://github.com/expo/fyi/blob/main/face-detector-removed.md#expo-face-detector-has-been-removed-from-expo-go).